# How to get Contact numbers by contact name using blackberry api

Tags: blackberry

How to get all contact numbers for a Contact when searching by contact name.
Given a contact name how can we search the address book and get all the contact numbers associated with the contact.

Comment: Have you took a look at this http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/javax/microedition/pim/PIM.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

get the contact list and search for your contact name between the contacts

```
    BlackBerryContactList contList = (BlackBerryContactList)PIM.getInstance().openPIMList(PIM.CONTACT_LIST,PIM.READ_ONLY);
            Enumeration er = contList.items();
            while (er.hasMoreElements())
            {
                BlackBerryContact c = (BlackBerryContact)er.nextElement();
if ((contList.isSupportedField(BlackBerryContact.NAME)) && (c.countValues(BlackBerryContact.NAME) > 0))
                {
                    String[] name = c.getStringArray(BlackBerryContact.NAME, 0);
                    String firstName = name[BlackBerryContact.NAME_GIVEN];
                    String lastName = name[BlackBerryContact.NAME_FAMILY];
                    fullname = "";
                    if (firstName != null)
                    {
                        fullname += firstName + " ";
                    }
```

//check if the name is the name you want

//here is the code snippet to iterate all phone nrs of a contact
if ((contList.isSupportedField(BlackBerryContact.TEL)) && (c.countValues(BlackBerryContact.TEL) > 0)) {
                    numValues = 0;
                    try {
                        numValues = c.countValues(BlackBerryContact.TEL);
                    } catch (Exception localException) {
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < numValues; ++i) {
                        if (c.getAttributes(BlackBerryContact.TEL, i) == BlackBerryContact.ATTR_WORK)
                            worknumber = c.getString(BlackBerryContact.TEL, i);
                        else if (c.getAttributes(BlackBerryContact.TEL, i) == BlackBerryContact.ATTR_HOME)
                            homenumber = c.getString(BlackBerryContact.TEL, i);
                        else if (c.getAttributes(BlackBerryContact.TEL, i) == BlackBerryContact.ATTR_MOBILE)
                            mobilenumber = c.getString(BlackBerryContact.TEL, i);
                        else if (c.getAttributes(BlackBerryContact.TEL, i) == BlackBerryContact.ATTR_OTHER)
                            othernumber = c.getString(115, i);
                        else if (c.getAttributes(BlackBerryContact.TEL, i) == BlackBerryContact.ATTR_PAGER)
                            pagernumber = c.getString(BlackBerryContact.TEL, i);
                        else if (c.getAttributes(BlackBerryContact.TEL, i) == BlackBerryContact.ATTR_FAX) {
                            faxnumber = c.getString(BlackBerryContact.TEL, i);
                        }
                    }

```
                System.out.println("---<><><>Mobile Phone Nr: " + mobilenumber);
                System.out.println("---<><><>Work Phone Nr: " + worknumber);
                System.out.println("---<><><>Home Phone Nr: " + homenumber);
                System.out.println("---<><><>Pager Nr: " + pagernumber);
                System.out.println("---<><><>Fax Nr: " + faxnumber);
                System.out.println("---<><><>Other Nr: " + othernumber);
            }
```

}

Comment: HI Alex sorry for the late response. I have seen your post and am convinced with the logic. Did not find time to implement and check but will do and post back confirming whether it is working so that it will be use full for other users

Comment: I have implemented this logic and it works. In the code that users might place at comment 
//check if the name is the name you want
in the code that Alex has explained
we should be comparing using the equalsIgnoreCase method. For example 
if(fullname.equalsIgnoreCase(userSelectedContactName)){
This would do the comparison correctly more information about this method at in the API reference at 
http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/index.html

Thanks Alex