# Using PIM, how to detect what is the attribute which is retrieved using Contact.TEL and index?

Tags: blackberry, java-me, contacts, contact-list, pim

I'm looping over all attributes of  the `Contact.TEL` field to retrieve names and data, so that I can display something like this: 
*HOME:* +2034953213 
*WORK:* +2033923959 
*MOBILE:* +20179083008 
I've retrived the values (+2034953213, +2033923959, +20179083008) successfully using PIM api, but I didn't know **how to detect what are the attributes corresponding to the values which I retrieved: (HOME, WORK or MOBILE ...etc) ?**
How Can I detect that +2034953213 is either the 'HOME' or 'WORK' or 'MOBILE' ? 
Same question for the other retrieved values ?

Here's my code:

```
ContactList contactList = (ContactList)PIM.getInstance().openPIMList(PIM.CONTACT_LIST, PIM.READ_WRITE);
Enumeration contactListItems = contactList.items();
while (contactListItems.hasMoreElements()) {
    Contact contact = (Contact)contactListItems.nextElement();
    int telephonesCount = contact.countValues(Contact.TEL);
    for(int i=0; i< telephonesCount; ++i) {
        String number = contact.getString(Contact.TEL, i); 
        // I want here to know what is the current attribute that i retrieved its value ?
        // I mean its value not its index (either HOME, WORK or MOBILE ...etc)
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385961/how-to-get-contact-numbers-by-contact-name-using-blackberry-api/2432585#2432585

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer for those who are interested:

```
ContactList contactList = (ContactList)PIM.getInstance().openPIMList(PIM.CONTACT_LIST, PIM.READ_WRITE);
Enumeration contactListItems = contactList.items();
while (contactListItems.hasMoreElements()) {
    Contact contact = (Contact)contactListItems.nextElement();
    int telephonesCount = contact.countValues(Contact.TEL);
    for(int i=0; i< telephonesCount; ++i) {
        String number = contact.getString(Contact.TEL, i); 
        int attribute = contact.getAttributes(BlackBerryContact.TEL, i);
        if (attribute == Contact.ATTR_MOBILE)
            // It's a mobile phone number, do whatever you want here ...
        else if (attribute == Contact.ATTR_HOME)
            // It's a home phone number, do whatever you want here ...
        else if (attribute == Contact.ATTR_WORK)
            // It's a work phone number, do whatever you want here ...
        // check other types the same way ...
    }
}
```